# future returned by `check_rss_task` is not `Send` when using tokio to start schedule task

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to use rust tokio to start some peroid schedule task, the peroid task will produce some data to message queue, this is the minimal reproduce code `main.rs`:

```
#![allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
extern crate openssl;

use std::time::Duration;

use celery::task::TaskResult;
use env_logger::Env;
use log::{info, error};
use structopt::StructOpt;
use tokio::time;

pub mod rss;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::Builder::from_env(Env::default().default_filter_or("info")).init();
    let task: tokio::task::JoinHandle<()> = tokio::spawn(check_rss_task());
    match task.await {
        Ok(_) => info!("success!"),
        Err(_) => error!("schedule task failed!"),
    };
    
}

pub async fn check_rss_task() {
    let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(35000));
    loop {
        interval.tick().await;
        let check_result = init_impl(CeleryOpt::Consume);
        check_result.await;
    }
}

#[celery::task]
fn add(x: i32, y: i32) -> TaskResult<i32> {
    info!("consumed message:{}{}", x, y);
    Ok(x + y)
}

pub async fn init_impl(opt: CeleryOpt) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let redis_addr =
        std::env::var("REDIS_ADDR").unwrap_or_else(|_| "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/".into());
    info!("redis addr:{}", redis_addr);
    let my_app = celery::app!(
        broker = RedisBroker { redis_addr },
        tasks = [
            add
        ],
        task_routes = [
            "buggy_task" => "buggy-queue",
            "*" => "celery",
        ],
        prefetch_count = 2,
        heartbeat = Some(10)
    )
    .await?;

    match opt {
        CeleryOpt::Consume => {
            my_app.display_pretty().await;
            my_app.consume_from(&["celery", "buggy-queue"]).await?;
        }
        CeleryOpt::Produce { tasks } => {
            if tasks.is_empty() {
                my_app.send_task(add::new(1, 2)).await?;
            } else {
                for task in tasks {
                    match task.as_str() {
                        "add" => my_app.send_task(add::new(1, 2)).await?,
                        _ => panic!("unknown task"),
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    };

    my_app.close().await?;
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(
    name = "celery_app",
    about = "Run a Rust Celery producer or consumer.",
    setting = structopt::clap::AppSettings::ColoredHelp,
)]
pub enum CeleryOpt {
    Consume,
    Produce {
        #[structopt(possible_values = &["add", "buggy_task", "bound_task", "long_running_task"])]
        tasks: Vec<String>,
    },
}
```

when write the task logic, I am facing a issue that the compiler always shows error:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:13:58
    |
13  |     let task: tokio::task::JoinHandle<()> = tokio::spawn(check_rss_task());
    |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `check_rss_task` is not `Send`
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `dyn DeliveryStream<Item = Result<Box<dyn celery::broker::Delivery>, Box<dyn DeliveryError>>>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
```

the `Cargo.toml` look like this:

```
[package]
name = "rss-sync"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
celery="0.5.3"
env_logger="0.10.0"
tokio = { version = "1.29.1", features = ["full"] }
structopt = "0.3"
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
anyhow = "1.0.71"
async-trait = "0.1.71"
log = "0.4.0"
openssl = "*"
openssl-probe = "0.1.2"
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?